# Careers advertisement images are still using the old Stack Overflow icon

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs

Stack Overflow and Stack Overflow Careers are using the new Stack Overflow icon,

[image: so] [image: soc]

but the advertisements haven't had the face lift applied:

[image: foo] [image: bar]

Comment: [Some](http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/e669aa51cc0d45358045db867ef436be.png) [more](http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/f6830b35dbe94952b9804183cae231b8.png) [ads](http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/7b03b9d327834757b98b657002b37789.png) [here](http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/ed3b3bbfd4364176bfd1feb8506577ed.jpg)

Comment: Careers be like *Why you leave me behind main site? Why u do dis?*

Comment: It takes 6 to 8 weeks before the logo change propagates to Careers :P

Comment: Finally found a question before posting it as a duplicate! BTW "issue" still remains...