# McStackIconOverflow

Tags: discussion, design

Is it just me or does the top menu have too many burgers for a healthy diet nowadays?

The new one at the left seems a bit Wimpy compared to the others.

[image]

(Good <strike>buns</strike> puns may be upvoted and relished.)

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369106/how-do-i-hide-the-left-navigation-sidebar#comment597805_369107

Comment: Technical debt in web design: I'll gladly pay you Tuesday for a hamburger menu today!

Comment: I haven't decided if I agree with your main point, but +1 for the punnery.

Comment: Related: [Review queue updates](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357630/7586)

Comment: Yea rest of them are burgers but the SO icon is basically a bunch of fresh pancakes getting tossed on a plate :p.

Answer (score 11):

You **must** be hungry.

I only see one burger icon in your picture.

From right to left...

- The icon over on the right has been the icon of the larger Stack Exchange network for...quite some time now.  Its design has been emblematic and would be tough to mistake for a burger icon.

  [image]
- The review icon was the result of [a *lengthy* discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355236/the-new-review-icon-isnt-an-improvement) [about what the heck the original icon was meant to be](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301845/175248).  It's *really* not meant to be a menu at all, but an actual *icon*.
- Stack Overflow's icon may have [shrunk over the years](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/306829/1079354) (the number of lines has dropped from 6 to 5), but...I have a tough time thinking of that as a burger.
- The last burger menu actually is a burger.  Looks <s>delicious</s> good on mobile.

  [image]

Comment: Reference: my picture in the question. Left one: stereotypical burger menu beloved of no-one; SO icon, not a burger in isolation, but sandwiched between the other ones, well... it starts to take on that appearance; the review queue is obviously showing the wedge-shaped tomato slice shooting out of the side of the burger; finally, we all know the site selector is a stylised burger menu - just look at the ketchup dripping out of it. And as for that circle on a stick? It looks like the magnifying glass I would need to find any food in my kitchen this evening :)

Comment: The icon on the right is __not__ the SE network icon: count the bars. It's a cross between SE icon and a hamburger, and is designed to resemble both. It was referred to as a hamburger in [topbar design discussions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/301086)

Comment: @user6655984 You know you have a great design when the user has to literally "count the bars" to distinguish between icons and menus. That's what they mean by "interactive" these days

Comment: I didn't even know that the 3 bars was called a "hamburger menu" until the SO icon re-design. Someone was being smart and noticed the resemblance between the old logo and hamburger menus. As for what a user would expect to happen after clicking on it, that's another story.

Comment: It should be noted that you don't even see the new left-hand hamburger menu unless you go into your profile and disable the left sidebar. So you should not be surprised or confused when you see it because you only see it if you chose to see it.

Comment: Surely the 5-line logo just means we're getting a triple stacked burger sandwiched in a lovely buttered brioche? At least that's what I'm hoping for my dinner this evening.

Comment: @AndrewMorton It's not really like that, no.

Comment: @TylerH Or make your window narrower, which is possible these days.

Comment: @TylerH "So you should not be surprised or confused when you see it because you only see it if you chose to see it." -- Neither the checkbox label nor the description underneath mentions that this icon will be shown instead. It makes sense when you think about it, but initially, a reaction of surprise or confusion is perfectly understandable.

Comment: @TylerH Ouch, I didn't even know I can disable the left sidebar; I suddenly noticed it appear a few days ago to my great annoyance; thanks for your hint, I now run scrambling to search for my Settings and disable it ASAP. *Thank you, good sir!* Some horizontal space reclaimed, was starting to feel suffocating...

Comment: The [so] icon is obviously a tall-stacked burger or a stack of burger buns on a plate that's in the middle of "overflowing" (falling over).

Comment: @Dukeling It's a stack of pancakes actually, but, yes.